# Retrieving the values ​of an event on 'QMediaPlayer' from Quasar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

I would like to retrieve the `curTime` and `remaining` value of the event in my QMediaPlayer component as cleanly as possible.

I have tested several syntaxes, but without success.

Example of my code:

```
this.$root.$on('timeupdate', (curTime, remaining) => {
    console.log('curTime: ', curTime)
    console.log('remaining', remaining)
}))
```

[Quasar Doc](https://quasarframework.github.io/quasar-ui-qmediaplayer/docs)

[image]

Do you have an idea ? thanks in advance

Comment: Show your attempts in code, please

Comment: I added an example of my code, I wanted to go through `this.$root.$on`.

Comment: Did you try something like `@timeupdate="onTimeUpdate"`?

Comment: No, but how would this translate syntactically?

Comment: This piece of code should be among other options of a player in a template. And of course, you should define the method `onTimeUpdate` with `(curTime, param2)` signature

Comment: This syntax works perfectly. Great, thank you @Anatoly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this `@timeupdate="onTimeUpdate"`:

In a template

```
// other component options
@timeupdate="onTimeUpdate"
```

In code:

```
methods: {
  onTimeUpdate(curTime, remaining) {
    console.log('curTime: ', curTime)
    console.log('remaining', remaining)
  }
}
```